# Can't make Clockwordmod Tether on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: usb, android, make, configure

I'm trying to install Clockwordmod Tether on my Ubuntu 16.10 laptop in order to facilitate USB tethering with [the corresponding app on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.tether&hl=en).

I've downloaded and extracted the [Tether tar file](http://download.clockworkmod.com/tether/tether-linux.tgz). The instructions for installation are very simple. Just run the following in a terminal:

```
cd /home/username/Tether/node
./configure
make
```

But when I run `make`, it always ends in this error:

```
../deps/v8/src/checks.h:251:22: warning: typedef ‘__StaticAssertTypedef__125’ locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
     SEMI_STATIC_JOIN(__StaticAssertTypedef__, __LINE__)
                      ^
../deps/v8/src/checks.h:241:39: note: in definition of macro ‘SEMI_STATIC_JOIN_HELPER’
 #define SEMI_STATIC_JOIN_HELPER(a, b) a##b
                                       ^
../deps/v8/src/checks.h:251:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘SEMI_STATIC_JOIN’
     SEMI_STATIC_JOIN(__StaticAssertTypedef__, __LINE__)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../deps/v8/src/checks.h:283:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘STATIC_CHECK’
 #define STATIC_ASSERT(test)  STATIC_CHECK(test)
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../deps/v8/src/v8utils.h:125:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘STATIC_ASSERT’
   STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(T) == kPointerSize);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../deps/v8/src/elements.h:32:0,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/objects-inl.h:38,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/v8.h:60,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/accessors.cc:28:
../deps/v8/src/objects.h: At global scope:
../deps/v8/src/objects.h:5017:44: error: left operand of shift expression ‘(-1 << 3)’ is negative [-fpermissive]
   static const int kElementsKindMask = (-1 << kElementsKindShift) &
                                        ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../deps/v8/src/objects.h:7152:36: error: left operand of shift expression ‘(-8 << 26)’ is negative [-fpermissive]
       (~kMaxCachedArrayIndexLength << kArrayIndexHashLengthShift) |
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
deps/v8/tools/gyp/v8_base.target.mk:209: recipe for target '/home/username/Tether/node/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/accessors.o' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/username/Tether/node/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/accessors.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/username/Tether/node/out'
Makefile:26: recipe for target 'node' failed
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

Looking on the net, it was suggested to install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev cmake g++ lib32ncurses5 nodejs-legacy
```

But this didn't help. I also saw that it might have something to do with a Python version issue, but I could not find user level instructions on how to deal with that.

Is there a way I can resolve this and install Tether on my Ubuntu laptop? And is the solution something that can be explained in terms that someone who knows nothing about `configure` or `make` can understand?

***Update:***

Thanks to [DropHammer99's answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/871651/17041), it seems I was able to successfully compile the program. This is how the `XXFLAGS=-fpermissive make` command ended after a few minutes:

```
  LINK(target) /home/username/Tether/node/out/Release/node: Finished
  touch /home/username/Tether/node/out/Release/obj.target/node_dtrace_header.stamp
  touch /home/username/Tether/node/out/Release/obj.target/node_dtrace_provider.stamp
  touch /home/username/Tether/node/out/Release/obj.target/node_dtrace_ustack.stamp
  touch /home/username/Tether/node/out/Release/obj.target/node_etw.stamp
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/username/Tether/node/out'
ln -fs out/Release/node node
```

Unfortunately, though, when I first ran the program as instructed in the `README` file, it crashed with this error:

```
~/Tether$ sudo linux/run.sh
[sudo] password for username: 
~/Tether
Starting Tether...
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
linux/run.sh: line 39: 21096 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $NODE/node tether.js
```

**Is this program just not going to work, or is there something I can do to resolve this segmentation fault error?**

Comment: I just had a look. The Clockworkmod-tether tar gz file contains source code from 2012. It might be hard to make that work properly. And perhaps a silly question : usb tethering worked fine on a smart phone I've used in the last few months (On Android 6.x, wifi on the phone, usb tethering, Internet to a desktop), without root privileges. Does you phone or your phone company restrict you in using tethering ?

Comment: @albertj, thanks for responding. The tethering function has been hobbled by the data service company I originally purchased the phone from.

Answer (score 6):

That error is the C++ compiler complaining about some usable but less than ideal code.  With the right command line options, you can tell the compiler to ignore code issues like that and keep going.  This isn't always the best solution, but it will get things to compile and work.

First, run `make clean` to get rid of anything left behind from your old build attempt.

Then, run `CXXFLAGS=-fpermissive make` to try again with the C++ compiler downgrading those code issues to warnings.

I was able to reproduce your error on my 64-bit 16.10 install, and this workaround allowed the build to get past that error for me.

Unfortunately, the build seemed to fail further along with this issue:

```
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/username/work/Tether/node/out'
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/username/work/Tether/node/out/Release/lib.host:/home/username/work/Tether/node/out/Release/lib.target:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd ../deps/v8/tools/gyp; mkdir -p /home/username/work/Tether/node/out/Release/obj.target/v8_snapshot/geni; "/home/username/work/Tether/node/out/Release/mksnapshot" --log-snapshot-positions --logfile "/home/username/work/Tether/node/out/Release/obj.target/v8_snapshot/geni/snapshot.log" "/home/username/work/Tether/node/out/Release/obj.target/v8_snapshot/geni/snapshot.cc"
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
deps/v8/tools/gyp/v8_snapshot.target.mk:13: recipe for target '/home/username/work/Tether/node/out/Release/obj.target/v8_snapshot/geni/snapshot.cc' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/username/work/Tether/node/out/Release/obj.target/v8_snapshot/geni/snapshot.cc] Error 139
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/username/work/Tether/node/out'
Makefile:26: recipe for target 'node' failed
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

I'm still looking into that issue.  Try the initial workaround, as maybe your system won't hit the second issue that mine did.

**Update**: I was able to sidestep that second issue by telling the config tool to skip the snapshot step.  Unfortunately, I have no idea what the snapshot step is supposed to do, and am afraid I might just be postponing a failure until later.  If you want to try this second workaround too, here is a command sequence to try:

```
make distclean
./configure --without-snapshot
CXXFLAGS=-fpermissive make
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was able to compile with your `XXFLAGS=-fpermissive make` command, and fortunately I did not hit the second issue you described. However, when I ran the program, there was some kind of `segmentation fault` error. Is that something that can be resolved in the compile process? I've updated my question with the new situation and output.

Comment: Segmentation fault errors are much more difficult to resolve, most likely outside the scope of the compile process.

Comment: Well, that's disappointing. Thanks for helping anyway. `:)`

Comment: the segfault suggests that the permissive make was too permissive and built broken code or possibly its linked with an unexpected version of a library.

Comment: I awarded this answer the bounty because, a) I had to award it because the deadline coming up, and b) although all the answers here were very helpful and appreciated, this answer did technically get me over the compiling issue which was the original problem outlined in the question.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Clockwordmod Tether linux app is out-of-date and needs a significant maintenance. I have compiled node with help of above answers. But it gave

`linux/run.sh: line 39: 25901 Segmentation fault      $NODE/node tether.js`

error. When I check its node version, I saw that *v0.8.14*. This version is very very old that it's out of documentation. When I edited run.sh file and make it use my system installed nodejs (v4.8.2), it failed message:
`[TypeError: os.setupTun is not a function]`

As being gnu/linux users, we need to find another alternative up-to-date solution this application!

Answer (score 2):

I have a fix for now.

- Go in file: `spaces.cc` in `node/deps/v8/src`
- Go to function: `bool PagedSpace::AdvanceSweeper` (approximately line 2274)
- Add `return true;` at the beginning of the method.

Do:

```
make distclean
./configure --without-snapshot
CXXFLAGS=-fpermissive make
```

Run tether:

```
sudo linux/run.sh
```

It connects and is in the network manager!

Comment: I was successfully connected for few minutes, then the error "./run.sh: line 39: 22873 Segmentation fault      $NODE/node tether.js" occurs and the connection is lost.
is there a solution ?

Comment: I  had the same segfault, and I solved it by commenting out a the entire do-while loop in the method. The fix can be found here. https://github.com/bemehiser/Tether

Answer (score 1):

**Re from:Bob Dickens Jr/BobDCoder,2017**
I am not sure where to reply to this issue, so I hope this is the right place.

I seen some errors that are explainable in the build error and wish to comment on them as I am sure it will take the errors away and might further the compile.

**./run.sh: line 38: ../linux/adb: No such file or directory** This issue is related to the Tether/Linux you will find a run.sh and there is a line right below **cd ../node**that needs to be edited. Find **../linux/adb** and change this line to **adb start-server** if you did a install of ADB, or **/your/path/to/adb  adb start-server** if you simply copy and pasted adb in /usr/bin/adb or some other directory.

That should remove that **../linux/adb** Error

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and i downloaded the rar file you mentioned above, and ran

`./configure &&  make`

I managed to build without errors, here is my [make log for build](http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3s/1484290157925.txt) , have you tried doing `make clean` and then `./configure && make` after you installed those new packages?

### Update:

@Questioner

Here was my output after i ran `~/Documents/Tether/linux/run.sh` as root.

```
~/Documents/Tether/linux
  Starting Tether...
 ./run.sh: line 38: ../linux/adb: No such file or directory
  Opening tun device.
  Opening tun device: /dev/net/tun
  Forking worker.
  Opening tun device.
  adb binary path: "/home/username/Documents/Tether/linux/adb"
  Checking phone status...
  tun worker initialized.
  { [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh: 1:/home/username/Documents/Tether/linux/adb: not found
  ] killed: false, code: 127, signal: null }
  Fatal error setting up TCP listener. (Exiting)
  A possible cause may be that a "node.exe" processes was left     dangling.
  Please kill any node processes you find running.
  This may also be cause by a firewall that disallows connections to   Tether.

  /home/username/Documents/Tether/node-tuntap/tuntap.js:558
  exitTether();
  ^
   ReferenceError: exitTether is not defined
   at Server.<anonymous> (/home/username/Documents/Tether/node-tuntap/tuntap.js:558:7)
   at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
   at Server._listen2.self._handle.onconnection (net.js:894:14)
   at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
   TCP Catcher worker has died. Exiting.
   { '0': 1, '1': null }
```

I guess the reasons why Tether is not running in this case would be:

1. `nodejs-legacy` is not installed (from `run.sh` line 39:`$NODE/node tether.js`),
2. Android SDK is not installed    (from `run.sh` line 38: `../linux/adb start-server`).

But i did not get any segmentation fault error. I have no idea about Nodejs, have you tried if `node` works properly as standalone command?

Seems like your `..adb/server start-server` has been executed successfully. It looks like there's a problem with `$NODE/node tether.js` on line 39. Here,`tether.js` file is the first argument to `node` command. I would try to execute `node tether.js` as a standalone command on the terminal.

Comment: Thank you for answering. After a successful compile, are you able to successfully run the program? I was able to successfully compile the program with the command `XXFLAGS=-fpermissive make`, but, I couldn't run it, as I've described in my updated question.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I checked that I have `nodejs-legacy` installed, and I also installed the Android SDK. Unfortunately, when I run the program I get the same segmentation fault error. It seems this is simply not going to work.

Comment: You're welcome! It seems you are not the only person who has `Segmenation fault(core dumped)` issue with `node`  [See here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2763) .  The issue seemed to have resolved for some people when they recompiled thedependencies using `npm rebuild`

Comment: Thanks for the additional tip. I had to install `npm`, and then I ran `npm rebuild`, but unfortunately it did not solve the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

When you get a segfault its usually a mismatch of libraries causing unexpected behaviour.

a segfault will cause a core dump, this is a dump to a file of the running state of the program just before i crashed , you can use this to debug why it crashed. This is complex stuff.

by default core dumping is often switched off , to switch it on you will need to ensure your ulimit settings allow a core file to be made , you can then load this core file in to a debugger and have it show you where it got stuck.

to configure your session to allow cores to be generated:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

then run your program and allow it to segfault and create a file called core

to diagnose it you can use the gnu debugger GDB (where your program is called programname and the corefile is called core)

```
sudo apt-get install gdb
gdb programname core
```

the program will then run up to the point where it segfaults and you will get a prompt , you can enter "bt" to get a backtrace which should point you at the origin of the problem. This info will be of use in a bug report even if you don't understand it.

Often compiled code is stripped of its debug info which can make this approach much harder.

For more info - http://bl0rg.krunch.be/segfault-gdb-strace.html

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried running the `ulimit -c unlimited` command before the Tether command, but it didn't change anything. I then tried running `gdp programname corefile`, but it simply said `gdp command not found`.  After that, I'm afraid your description is way above me, so I'm not totally sure what else I should be doing.

Comment: sorry , there were missing bits , i've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

To correct my failing minds typos

**Re from:Bob Dickens Jr/BobDCoder,2017**

I seen an error that is explainable in the build error results and wish to suggest several thoughts of correction as I am sure it will take that error out of the picture and might further the compile and make.

**./run.sh: line 38: ../linux/adb: No such file or directory**
This issue is obviously related to a file in the **Tether/Linux** directory/folder called **run.sh** which needs to be edited.

There is a line right below **cd ../node** that needs to be edited so **Find (line 38)../linux/adb** and change this line to **adb start-server** if you did a automatic install of ADB.

**cd ../node**

**adb start-server**

An automatic install it should have automatically set the path in the above setup!

However if you manually created a directory and copied **adb to /usr/bin/adb** 
OR If you copied adb to some other directory then you may need to change the lines to the code below. 
**cd /your/path/to/adb adb start-server**.

However since line **37** reads **cd ../node** and puts you in the node directory, it is unclear if the second change in directory (line 38)**cd /some/custom/directory adb start-server**
will cause the compiler or **run.sh** to error again as it would take you out of the node directory as it runs.

The reason for this for this is **cd ..** in the code and needs to be pointed out. **cd ..** has for decades been used to back out of the current directory by one level, So.....

- ( run.sh ) is in tether/linux directory to start with and where it is running.
- But in the **run.sh** code itself, when it runs, it tells run.sh to back out of the **/linux** sub-directory to **/Tether** with a "cd .." portion of (line 37) the command!
- With the finish of the command on line 37 **/node** it also tells it to switch to the **node** directory. 
  .
  .
  .
  If such is the case I took the liberty of re-coding line 37, 38 and a new lines as to correct this issue.

**cd ../node**

**cd /usr/bin/adb**

**adb start-server**

**cd /YourAbsolute/path/back/to/Tether/node**

or you could simply try removing line 37s code **cd ../node** and trying the below

**cd /usr/bin/adb**

**adb start-server**

**cd /YourAbsolute/path/back/to/Tether/node**

It is unclear to me if Node needs to run before starting the adb server or if Node can run after the adb server has started (I think logically the later) would work.

With a little playing, that should remove the **../linux/adb Error**

Answer (score 0):

Another trick to try is short,quick and simple but may defeat the problem. Make a copy of the newer installed adb file and paste it into the tether/linux directory with run.sh and let it overwrite the older copy of adb as it obviously does not work.

I honestly think that the old adb is corrupt or maybe its just sleepy! lol

I haven't tried this workaround myself, but it's is at least worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04LTS

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
sudo ln -s /android/platform-tools/adb /bin/adb
sudo apt-get install npm 
npm install chainsaw
```

Operational.

No editing of files. Unfortunately unsure if the first two commands are related as this was something I was experimenting with the prior night.